# Python Pandas set_index function: KeyError: "None of [] are in the columns"

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am currently going through the book "Hands-On machine learning... " by Aurèlion Gèron. However, I am getting the following error message: (it is somewhat cumbersome to reproduce because the following two CSV downloads are required: [OECD](https://stats.oecd.org/index.aspx?DataSetCode=BLI) [IMF](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/weo/2016/01/weodata/weorept.aspx?pr.x=32&pr.y=8&sy=2015&ey=2015&scsm=1&ssd=1&sort=country&ds=.&br=1&c=512%2C668%2C914%2C672%2C612%2C946%2C614%2C137%2C311%2C962%2C213%2C674%2C911%2C676%2C193%2C548%2C122%2C556%2C912%2C678%2C313%2C181%2C419%2C867%2C513%2C682%2C316%2C684%2C913%2C273%2C124%2C868%2C339%2C921%2C638%2C948%2C514%2C943%2C218%2C686%2C963%2C688%2C616%2C518%2C223%2C728%2C516%2C558%2C918%2C138%2C748%2C196%2C618%2C278%2C624%2C692%2C522%2C694%2C622%2C142%2C156%2C449%2C626%2C564%2C628%2C565%2C228%2C283%2C924%2C853%2C233%2C288%2C632%2C293%2C636%2C566%2C634%2C964%2C238%2C182%2C662%2C453%2C960%2C968%2C423%2C922%2C935%2C714%2C128%2C862%2C611%2C135%2C321%2C716%2C243%2C456%2C248%2C722%2C469%2C942%2C253%2C718%2C642%2C724%2C643%2C576%2C939%2C936%2C644%2C961%2C819%2C813%2C172%2C199%2C132%2C733%2C646%2C184%2C648%2C524%2C915%2C361%2C134%2C362%2C652%2C364%2C174%2C732%2C328%2C366%2C258%2C734%2C656%2C144%2C654%2C146%2C336%2C463%2C263%2C528%2C268%2C923%2C532%2C738%2C944%2C578%2C176%2C537%2C534%2C742%2C536%2C866%2C429%2C369%2C433%2C744%2C178%2C186%2C436%2C925%2C136%2C869%2C343%2C746%2C158%2C926%2C439%2C466%2C916%2C112%2C664%2C111%2C826%2C298%2C542%2C927%2C967%2C846%2C443%2C299%2C917%2C582%2C544%2C474%2C941%2C754%2C446%2C698%2C666&s=NGDPDPC&grp=0&a=).

**Error message**:

> File "C:\Users\xxx\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
> line 4548, in set_index
> raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
>
> KeyError: "None of ['Country'] are in the columns"

The code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import sklearn.linear_model

oecd_bli = pd.read_csv("BLI_24092020220751169.csv", thousands =',')

gdp_per_capita = pd.read_csv("gdp_per_capita.csv", thousands =',', delimiter ='\t', encoding =' latin1', na_values="n/a")

def prepare_country_stats(oecd_bli, gdp_per_capita):
    oecd_bli = oecd_bli[oecd_bli["INEQUALITY"]=="TOT"]
    oecd_bli = oecd_bli.pivot(index="Country", columns="Indicator", values="Value")
    gdp_per_capita.rename(columns={"2015":"GDP per capita"}, inplace=True)
    gdp_per_capita.set_index("Country", inplace=True)
    full_country_stats = pd.merge(left=oecd_bli, right=gdp_per_capita,
                                  left_index=True, right_index=True)
    full_country_stats.sort_values(by="GDP per capita", inplace=True)
    remove_indices = [0, 1, 6, 8, 33, 34, 35]
    keep_indices = list(set(range(36)) - set(remove_indices))
    return full_country_stats[["GDP per capita", 'Life satisfaction']].iloc[keep_indices]

country_stats = prepare_country_stats(oecd_bli, gdp_per_capita) 
X = np.c_[country_stats["GDP per capita"]] 
y = np.c_[country_stats["Life satisfaction"]] 

# Visualize the data 
country_stats.plot( kind ='scatter', X ="GDP per capita", y ='Life satisfaction') 
plt.show() 

# Select a linear model 
model = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression() 

# Train the model 
model.fit(X, y) 

# Make a prediction for Cyprus 
X_new = [[22587]] 
# Cyprus's GDP per capita 

print( model.predict(X_new))
```

However, already in the function I get stuck. The error seems to be related to the `set_index` command, which I thought was a very reliable function. Of course, in my CSV file the `Country` column is present.

Here is a screenshot of the `gdp_per_capita` CSV.

[image: gdp_per_capita]

If anyone takes the time to reproduce, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are setting `delimiter` correctly? In the screenshot it seems from the header that `;` is your `delimiter`.

Comment: Jeez, how could have have overlooked that. I wish I could blame my German PC settings for nt paying attention. Many thanks!

Comment: @รยקคгรђשค Thanks so much for clearing this up - this comment helped me out as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of changes required in your code:

Change this line:

```
gdp_per_capita = pd.read_csv("gdp_per_capita.csv", thousands =',', delimiter ='\t', encoding =' latin1', na_values="n/a")
```

to this (remove the `encoding='latin1'`):

```
gdp_per_capita = pd.read_csv("gdp_per_capita.csv", thousands =',', delimiter ='\t', na_values="n/a")
```

And change this:

```
country_stats.plot(kind='scatter', X="GDP per capita", y='Life satisfaction')
```

To this (Capital X to x):

```
country_stats.plot(kind='scatter', x="GDP per capita", y='Life satisfaction')
```

I was able to get a scatter plot after these 2 changes:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I did notice that the X was in CAP, but thought since in CAP throughout, it wouldn't matter

Comment: Sorry for the follow up. I noticed that you plot the regression in the above graph. Is this caused by your IDE? I use Spyder and it did not plot the regression

Comment: I use Pycharm/VS Code. A separate window opens up when you run matplotlib.

Comment: Why did you accept the other answer? Just wondering.

Comment: I think I did accept your answer mate. Not sure what happened :) thanks again

Answer (score 1):

- Reading the `gdp_per_capita` csv with `'latin'` encoding reads the `Country` column as `ï»¿Country`. Therefore, I suggest `'utf-8'` encoding, which resolves this issue.
- You had a typo in the `scatterplot`, which [@NYC coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6168323/nyc-coder) has already pointed out.

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.linear_model

oecd_bli = pd.read_csv("BLI_26092020152902439.csv", thousands =',')

gdp_per_capita = pd.read_csv("gdp_per_capita.csv", delimiter = '\t', thousands =',', encoding ='utf-8', na_values="n/a")

def prepare_country_stats(oecd_bli, gdp_per_capita):
    oecd_bli = oecd_bli[oecd_bli["INEQUALITY"]=="TOT"]
    oecd_bli = oecd_bli.pivot(index="Country", columns="Indicator", values="Value")
    gdp_per_capita.rename(columns={"2015":"GDP per capita"}, inplace=True)
    print(gdp_per_capita)
    gdp_per_capita.set_index("Country", inplace=True)
    full_country_stats = pd.merge(left=oecd_bli, right=gdp_per_capita,
                                  left_index=True, right_index=True)
    full_country_stats.sort_values(by="GDP per capita", inplace=True)
    remove_indices = [0, 1, 6, 8, 33, 34, 35]
    keep_indices = list(set(range(36)) - set(remove_indices))
    return full_country_stats[["GDP per capita", 'Life satisfaction']].iloc[keep_indices]

country_stats = prepare_country_stats(oecd_bli, gdp_per_capita)
X = np.c_[country_stats["GDP per capita"]]
y = np.c_[country_stats["Life satisfaction"]]

# Visualize the data 
country_stats.plot( kind ='scatter', x ="GDP per capita", y ='Life satisfaction')
plt.show()

# Select a linear model 
model = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Train the model 
model.fit(X, y)

# Make a prediction for Cyprus 
X_new = [[22587]]
# Cyprus's GDP per capita 

print( model.predict(X_new))
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! Weirdly, for me works "Latin1". When I use "utf-8" I get the following: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 235638: invalid start byte

Comment: Glad it works. Please accept and upvote the answer if It helps you. So that people know that the issue is resolved.